# Should parents honor their children?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, kavod

What responsibility do parents have to their children vis a vis Kavod? General Kavod HaBerioth? Some level of relational Kavod like spouses have or like children have to their parents, only to a lesser extent?

Comment: (Sefer Machaneh Efrayim in the Hilchot Tzedaka section brings an opinion (from the Talmud?) that boys from the age of six and upward are not dependent on their parents and that anything the parents give to their children is tzedaka because they are no longer obligated to support them once they turn 6. ...i.e., kavod haberioth perhaps.

Comment: Where does it speak about what parents must provide for their children and until what age?

Comment: Sadly, and absurdly, related: http://gawker.com/5986916/man-sues-parents-for-not-loving-him-enough-seeks-200000-and-two-dominos-pizza-restaurants-in-damages

Answer (score 2):

There is an issur of onaas devarim(hurting with words) Vayikra 25:17 see Rashi. The Sefer HaChinuch 338 brings down that this applies to ones children as well. Hurting someone else feelings is a severe prohibition(even through a gesture it is assur).

ונוהגת מצוה זו בכל מקום ובכל זמן, בזכרים ונקבות, ואפילו בקטנים ראוי להזהר שלא להכאיבן בדברים יותר מדי, זולתי כמה שצריכין הרבה כדי שיקחו מוסר, שאפילו בבניו ובנותיו ובני ביתו של אדם, והמיקל בהם שלא לצערן בענינים אלה, ימצא חיים ברכה וכבוד.ועובר על זה והכאיב את חבירו בדברים, באותן שפירשו חכמים זכרונם לברכה כבעל תשובה ובחולה ובכיוצא בהן, עבר על לאו זה, אבל אין לוקין עליו לפי שאין בו מעשה וכמה מלקיות מבלי רצועה של עגל ביד האדון הַמְּצַוֶּה על זה, יתברך ויתעלה. see the full thing inside,

Comment: So are you saying that is the extent of one's responsibility to the honor of one's children, or that is the minimum?

Comment: This is one source I found,might be more not sure.

Comment: But this applies to everyone, not just your children. The Chinuch is saying *even* with children

Comment: That was part of the question. If you read the q again you will see tgat I answered the q.

Answer (score 0):

**There's none**, of course, besides the regular warnings and prohibitions toward any other Jewish fellow.

1. Hierarchical Honor as a Mitzvah(the only one found in the Torah) works only one way: Jews must honor G-d, [therefore] kids must honor parents and students must honor their Rabbis but not the opposite.
   The same applies to the Mitzvah of reverence (Mor'ah) of G-d, parents and Rabbis.
2. The obligation of honor is very vague and often confused/merged with the Mitzvah of reverence (Mora'ah). Basically, this includes two parts: 1. taking care (feeding, covering, escorting and otherwise serving) and 2. showing signs of cultural respect (standing before them, talking politely, not insulting etc). All of those apply one way, namely from the kids to their parents.
3. Parents ARE obligated to take care of the kids to a certain age (6 to 18), but this stems from the Mitzvah of Chesed (kindness) toward the helpless kids and not from honoring them.
4. However, it must be noted that since one is obligated on Chinuch and education of his kids, he might be advised to show some respect IN ORDER to educate them properly, and not as a standalone obligation. In other words, as respecting kids (especially in our times) might help to develop their love to Torah and Mitzvos one is advised to behave in such manner.